# Not deduced context in variadic function template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

The following code should be, as I know, "not deduced context" (or not?)

```
template <class... X, class Y>
void f(X... args, Y y)
{

}

int main()
{
    f(12);
    f<int, int, int>(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

but g++ 4.9 compiles it for both instantiations of `f` in `main`...
Can anybody explain?

Comment: Are the calls being optimized out?

Answer (score 1):

The first call `f(12)` is ill-formed. A parameter-pack that does not appear at the end of a parameter-declaration is a non-deduced context per [temp.deduct.type]/p5.7:

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> — [..]
>
> — **A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the *parameter-declaration-list***

Further in [temp.deduct.call]/p1:

> For a function parameter pack that occurs at the end of the *parameter-declaration-list*, the type `A` of each remaining argument of the call is compared with the type `P` of the *declarator-id* of the function parameter pack. Each comparison deduces template arguments for subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by the function parameter pack. **When a function parameter pack appears in a non-deduced context (14.8.2.5), the type of that parameter pack is never deduced.**
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```c++
> template<class ... Types> void f(Types& ...);
> template<class T1, class ... Types> void g(T1, Types ...);
> template<class T1, class ... Types> void g1(Types ..., T1);
>
> void h(int x, float& y) {
>     const int z = x;
>     f(x, y, z); // Types is deduced to int, float, const int
>     g(x, y, z); // T1 is deduced to int; Types is deduced to float, int
>     g1(x, y, z); // error: Types is not deduced
>     g1<int, int, int>(x, y, z); // OK, no deduction occurs
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Thus the parameter pack `X...` cannot be deduced by the function's arguments and template argument deduction fails. GCC accepts the first call instead of rejecting the template for not deducing `12` so it appears to be a bug.

The second call, `f<int, int, int>(1, 2, 3, 4)`, however, is well-formed according to [temp.deduct]/p6. The explicitly-specified template arguments are immediately substituted for the template parameters of the function template. This means `X = {int, int, int}`. Template argument deduction then proceeds with `Y` being deduced from the rightmost argument as `int`:

> At certain points in the template argument deduction process it is necessary to take a function type that makes use of template parameters and replace those template parameters with the corresponding template
> arguments. **This is done at the beginning of template argument deduction when any explicitly specified template
> arguments are substituted into the function type, and again at the end of template argument deduction
> when any template arguments that were deduced or obtained from default arguments are substituted.**

Note that also ([temp.deduct]/p2):

> There must not be more arguments than there are parameters **unless at least one parameter is a template parameter pack**, and there shall be an argument for each non-pack parameter.

Clang does not accept the last function call, but GCC does. I believe this to be a Clang bug.

---

Note that there is an open [CWG issue 1609](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1609) pertaining to the use of default-arguments following the occurrence of a parameter-pack. There's also [LLVM Bug 21774](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=21774) which disputes Clang's behavior in that context.

Answer (score 0):

That rule applies only to class templates, not functions, because the templates can be deduced for functions. If you try that on a class template, you'll see the error:

```
template <class... X, class Y>
class C {  // This won't compile.
};
```

For more information, please refer to Page 7 in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2242.pdf:

> If a template-parameter of a class template is a template parameter
>   pack, it must be the last template-parameter. Note: This is not a
>   requirementThese are not requirements for function templates because
>   template arguments might be deduced (14.8.2)